# Machine with finite number of states

Tags: probability

What is the correct method to solve following problem: Machine has ten states, is at the first state and on $i$th  turn, we know the probability $p_i$ to move from the current state to the next state. On probability $1-p_i$ we stay on the current state. How many steps $n$ we need to make sure that on $n$th turn we are on the $10$th state with probability $\geq \frac{1}{2}$?

Edit:

I figured out how matrixes will help to solve this problem. For example Wolfram Alpha gives that the matrix

```
[[1,0,0,0,0]] * [[6/10,4/10,0,0,0],[0,7/10,3/10,0,0],[0,0,8/10,2/10,0],[0,0,0,9/10,1/10],[0,0,0,0,1]]^n
```

has the last component less than $0.5$ if $n=17$ more that $0.5$ if $n=18$. So now I have to prove that the value of the last component forms an increasing function with respect to $n$. Any ideas how to prove that?

Comment: Can you solve the problem for a machine with $2$ states instead of $10$?

Comment: I think the probability than on $n$th turn we are on the second state is  $p_1+(1-p_1)p_1+(1-p_1)^2p_1+\ldots (1-p_1)^np_1=(p_1-1)((1-p_1)^n-1)+p_1$

Comment: Looks good for the 2 state machine. Can be simplified to $(1-p_1)^{n+1}$.

Comment: But how this helps to solve the general problem?

Comment: The idea is similar but can not really be done by hand easily. You would instead use a [transition matrix](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stochastic_matrix) to model the probabilities of switching between states. Evaluating this to the $n$th power gives the probabilities of being in different states after $n$ steps.

Comment: This is just a pure birth process.